# Performing a task when servers processing is finished

Tags: java, elasticsearch, redis, architecture, apache-zookeeper

I have different instances of same service running, which are consuming same message (unique message id is part of message) from the queue and updating its internal store. Now there is a requirement to send a message to a differnt topic only when all the services are finished processing the message, now these service can process the same message at differnt rate. And can be autoscaled.

Is there any solution which ensures that we send the message only when all the services have finished processing the message.

can there be any solution based on redis/ES, zookeeper config etc to ensure this or any other solution to handle this scenario (which also address the autoscaling)?

Comment: Not familiar with zookeeper, but if messages are from a queue, there would only be a single service instance that would receive the message and process it.  So the service could publish a message to another a queue/topic to say it was done.  Please clarify if that's not correct.

Comment: I am quite confused about how your system looks like but if you have some process that can handle endings of processes you might be able to setup a zookeeper Barrier - https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.5.0-alpha/recipes.html#sc_recipes_eventHandles